# Is it a good idea to initialize the object(entity) by using IDataRecord in the constructor?

Tags: c#

Or is it against some paradigm?

```
using System.Data;
//This is a read only entity
class Entity
{
    public Entity(IDataRecord data)
    {
       ID = (int)data["ID"];
       Name = data["Name"].ToString();
       Value = data["Value"] is DBNull ? default(int?) : (int)data["Value"];
    }
    public int ID { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public int? Value { get; }
}
```

How I use:

```
//...
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [ID],[Name],[Value] FROM [Table]", conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
            .Select(data => new Entity(data))
            .ToArray();
}
```

In the case of ensuring that it can be used correctly and safely, is this a good idea?

Or can be improved better?

Comment: I'd say no. If you want to create one of these objects and it hasn't been saved yet, you have no default constructor. So anyone trying to create an Entity (or an ORM trying to do so) would be unable to create it and then set the properties. But maybe you aren't using it like that, so it's sort of subjective.

Comment: @Nikki9696 If there is need to create it with a custom value, I will of course add a no-argument or full-property constructor. I think this is not a problem...

Comment: Just use initialization syntax with  properties instead like "new Entity { ID = (int)data["ID"], Name.......etc. etc}"